# update array of objects in localstorage without leaveing a null

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, local-storage

So I have 3 text input fields, the input I store in local storage as an array of objects.
Looks like that:

```
[{name: " Name1", description: "Description1", comment: "Comment1"},…]
0: {name: " Name1", description: "Description1", comment: "Comment1"}
1: {name: " Name2", description: "Description2", comment: "Comment2"}
2: {name: " Name3", description: "Description3", comment: "Comment3"}
```

I need to be able to delete any entry I choose and update local storage.

After JSON.parse I get an javascript object, not an array.
If I use delete[X] it leaves null -

```
[null, {name: " Name2", description: "Description2", comment: "Comment2"},…]
0: null
1: {name: " Name2", description: "Description2", comment: "Comment2"}
2: {name: " Name3", description: "Description3", comment: "Comment3"}
```

Is there any way to avoid that, I need entry be completely gone and update indexes so "name2..." would gain index 0 and so on.

Is there any way to do it?
Thanks!

Comment: how are you deleting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to remove `null` array items.

```js
let newVals = [null, {
  name: " Name2",
  description: "Description2",
  comment: "Comment2"
}, {
  name: " Name3",
  description: "Description3",
  comment: "Comment3"
}].filter(x => x);
console.log(newVals);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mutating the array, filter it out: Example:

```
const newArr = [...].filter(o => o.name != <name you want to remove>)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several options to do this.

Option 1: [.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

> The splice() method changes the contents of an array by removing or replacing existing elements and/or adding new elements in place.

```js
const data = [{name: " Name1", description: "Description1", comment: "Comment1"}, {name: " Name2", description: "Description2", comment: "Comment2"}, {name: " Name3", description: "Description3", comment: "Comment3"}];

const s = data.splice(1,1);

console.log(data, 'removed: =>', s);
```

Option 2: [.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

```js
const data = [{name: "Name1", description: "Description1", comment: "Comment1"}, {name: " Name2", description: "Description2", comment: "Comment2"}, {name: " Name3", description: "Description3", comment: "Comment3"}];


console.log(data.filter(item => item && item.name !== 'Name1'))
```

Option 3: [Loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete items from an array it's better you use array method

```
array.splice(index, 1);
```

If you want to delete item from the object

```
delete array[x]

let newArray = array.filter(x => x)
```

so newArray is without null value

Answer (score 0):

Always make sure to get the values, updated array and set it again. Hope this helps.

```
const data = [
  { name: " Name1", description: "Description1", comment: "Comment1" },
  { name: " Name2", description: "Description2", comment: "Comment2" },
  { name: " Name3", description: "Description3", comment: "Comment3" }
];

const setLS = arr => localStorage.setItem("my_data", JSON.stringify(arr));

const getLS = () => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("my_data"));

const removeItemLS = obj => {
  const current = getLS();
  setLS(current.filter(item => item.name !== obj.name));
};

setLS(data);
getLS();
// (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
removeItemLS({ name: " Name2" });
getLS();
// (2) [{…},{…}]
```